# C# server performance: how to exit foreach loop

Tags: c#

```
if (Properties.Settings.Default.ICMP_SERVER_LIST.ToString() != string.Empty)
{
    string ServersToPing = Properties.Settings.Default.ICMP_SERVER_LIST;
    string[] ServerArrays = ServersToPing.Split(new Char[] { ' ' },
        StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    foreach (string server in ServerArrays)
    {
        string host = server.Substring(0, server.IndexOf(':'));
        int port = Convert.ToInt32(server.Substring(server.LastIndexOf(":") + 1).ToString());
        string[] serverInfo = ServersToPing.Split(new Char[] { ' ' },
            StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        string res = PingServerViaICMP(server, RespTimeOut);
        Ping pingreq = new Ping();
        PingReply pingrep = pingreq.Send(host, 30 * 1000);
        res = string.Format("{0}:time={1}ms", pingrep.Address.ToString(),
            pingrep.RoundtripTime.ToString());
        txtLog.Text += host + ": " + res + "   " + Environment.NewLine;
    }
    Array.Clear(ServerArrays, ServerArrays.GetLowerBound(0), ServerArrays.GetLowerBound(0));
    ServersToPing = "";
}
```

There 7 server names and ports in app.config file. I am trying to hit the servers to get the time taken .I am getting the expected result but I am unable to get out of foreach loop. The results keeps on repeating.

Comment: Why do you have a foreach loop if you are clearing the array at the end? Based on that line I'd guess you don't even want a loop. are you trying to ping each server once? Your code is unclear; what are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to hit like 7 servers and trying to get the time taken to hit it. I am getting the expected output but it keeps on repeating same values. I guess its not exiting the for each loop.

Comment: ya I used timer. so is there anyother way I could do it.

Comment: If you only want this to occur once, don't set `Timer.Enabled = true` at the end of your tick method. (otherwise your timer will just keep getting called at the specified interval)

Comment: In the above code if I want to add toolstripstatus label showing which server is it presently hitting with details. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the code you posted.  Once you strip out all of the code that is either unnecessary or has nothing to do with the heart of the routine, you're left with:

```
string ServersToPing = "localhost:80 localhost:443";
string[] ServerArrays = ServersToPing.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

foreach (string server in ServerArrays)
{
    string host = server.Substring(0, server.IndexOf(':'));
    Ping pingreq = new Ping();
    PingReply pingrep = pingreq.Send(host, 30 * 1000);
    Console.WriteLine("{0}:time={1}ms", pingrep.Address.ToString(), pingrep.RoundtripTime.ToString());
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

And that code works just fine.

In your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20005725/i-am-trying-to-write-a-code-for-performance-logs-which-hits-several-icmp-server) on the same topic, **you seem to be launching this with a Timer. That will cause the code to be executed over and over again.**

Answer (score 1):

```
if (some_success_validation) 
{
  break;
}
```